# Force a page to be rendered in admin theme (overlay mode)

Tags: 7, theming

Is there a way to force a page to be rendered in admin theme, Like pages that their path begins with 'admin/'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a contrib module [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) that

> allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules
>   which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path,
>   taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties.
>   It can also be easily extended to support additional properties
>   exposed by other modules. In combination with Drupal's theme
>   inheritance and ThemeKey Properties you can easily achieve features
>   like:
>
> individually-styled channels a front-page / "splash" screen a
>   date/time-selected Christmas theme mobile themes for different
>   auto-detected mobile devices special themes for "limited" or "old"
>   browsers content, user, or role -specific themes indicating your
>   environment (production, staging, testing, sandbox, … ) testing your
>   redesign safely on a live server

Check also related question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/812/2916).

Answer (score 14):

You can also do this by making a custom module.

**Method 1**

Use this if you want to theme an existing page, based on Drupal's internal path (aka path source). This example uses [hook_custom_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7).

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_custom_theme() {
  // match node/1
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == '1') {
    return variable_get('admin_theme');
  }
}
```

**Method 2**

Use this if you want to theme an existing page, based on URL path (aka path alias). This example also uses [hook_custom_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7).

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_custom_theme() {
  // get arguments
  $arg = explode('/', substr(request_uri(), strlen(base_path())));
  // match {wildcard}/path 
  // Using strpos as $arg[1] may end up having stuff like so ?order=title&sort=asc
  if (isset($arg[1]) && strpos($arg[1], 'path') !== false && !isset($arg[2])) {
    return variable_get('admin_theme');
  }
}
```

**Method 3**

Use this if you want to theme and create a page. This example uses [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). To learn more, take a look at another [great article on hook_menu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62473/how-should-i-implement-hook-menu).

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();

  // match some/path
  $output['some/path'] = array(
    'title' => t('Page Title'),
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_page',
    'theme callback' => 'variable_get',
    'theme arguments' => array('admin_theme'),
  )
}

function MYMODULE_page() {
  return 'Hello world.';
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are a module developer, you can use [hook_admin_paths](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7) to define which paths are to be rendered with the administration theme.

Answer (score 4):

Simply give the page a path beginning with admin: 'admin/mypage'

Comment: Why the downvote? This functionality is in D7 core, the question does not specify which version, but at time of posters question D7 was released.

Comment: Yep, perfectly sensefull comment IMO.

Comment: it doesn't seem that custom pages beginning with 'admin/' necessarily load the admin theme.

Comment: perfect and simplistic for views!

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 1):

1. This functionality is now in D7 core.
2. There's a module that effectively exposes "hook_admin_paths" to the UI: 
   https://drupal.org/project/admin_theme