# trouble with hook_menu

Tags: routes

I am trying to set up a new menu item in Drupal 7 and not having any luck. I've tried several examples and have been successful at this in the past, but this is just not working.

The following code is in a module called directory, I keep getting a "page not found" error.

```
function directory_menu() {
  $items=array();

  $items['directory'] = array(
    'title' => 'Employee Directory',
    'page callback' => 'directory_content',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;    
}

function directory_content() {
  $content = array();

  $content['raw_markup'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => 'Testing',
  );

  return $content;
}
```

Comment: Have you installed the module and cleared the caches?

Comment: Also, check this [excellent guide on `hook_menu()`](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62473/how-to-implement-hook-menu/62474#62474)

Comment: Yes, I've cleared the cache and installed the menu. I've checked it and added access callback => TRUE, but it's still not working.  Is there some way to debug what's happening when it's adding the menu item?  Is there a way to do a dsm item?

Comment: Yep, just add `dsm($item);` into the menu hook and flush the caches. If you see your item, the hook is being called, and obviously if not, it's not

Comment: Thanks - it is showing in the dsm on cache clear - so something is working -  but it's still returning a page not found and the item doesn't show in the menu                      
... (Array, 1 element)

    directory (Array, 5 elements)
        title (String, 18 characters ) Employee Directory
        page callback (String, 17 characters ) directory_content | (Callback) directory_content();
        access arguments (Array, 1 element)
        type (Integer) 6
        access callback (Boolean) TRUE

The requested page "/directory" could not be found.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with your code so it must be something else in your installation. I'd suggest disabling any suspect modules. Also try changing the path and module name from "directory" to something less likely to clash with other code, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly ok. I installed it you can check the screenshot below. 
 [image]

Comment: Thanks to all I got it working - I think it was as @alfreda mentioned - issues with other modules