# Auto Complete displaying wrong for non-admin users

Tags: 7, ajax

I've recently started a module that runs an autocomplete via the taxonomy. It's attached to a form textarea element:

```
$form['bb_occupation'] = array(
    ...
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'taxonomy/autocomplete/field_occupations_list',
);
```

My issue is as follows, The options returned from the auto complete display correctly for admin/logged in users:
[image]

<sup>[*Full size image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2HJc.png)</sup>

While, if a non-admin/non logged in user visits said site, they're greeted with this:

[image]

<sup>[*Full size image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL6ln.png)</sup>

Where the options appear well off screen. I did a little research on Drupal & Google and came up with these:

[Autocomplete fields appear in wrong place for non-admins in...](https://www.drupal.org/node/1951584)

Which lead to an answer that did the following sort of deal (*[taken from here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1218684#comment-5444268)*):

```
$($input).parent().addClass('autocomplete-wrapper');
```

in the `autocomplete.js` and this:

```
.autocomplete-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

to the `system.base.css` files. That didn't work for me, and I've been playing with positioning for practically the whole day now, do you guys have any suggestions as to how I can amend/fix this?

It is **not** related to anything like this:

[(custom )Autocomplete won't work when the user is not logged](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/78956/39690)

as it isn't a custom function doing the autocomplete, it's through the taxonomy. 
It can't be a permissions error either because the menu with suggestions shows up, just not where it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think anonymous user doesn't have a permission of autocomplete. Can you please visit permission tab of your site. May be you get some luck!

Hold on, you are using taxonomy right, then please check this module permission. I think that time you get some luck.

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to autocomplete in the permissions section. But it can't be that, because if it was the case, it wouldn't show up at all, yet it does show up, just not where it is supposed to.

Comment: I editted my answer, please check...

Comment: I've looked at all the possible permissions related to that and nothing.