# How to use Form API

Tags: forms

I'm new to drupal, and especially new to drupal form API. I see all the documentation which seems to make sense. They miss one key instruction that you need to create .module / .info files. I have created those, and copied the code from into my module [Form example code drupal 6](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example_tutorial.inc/function/form_example_tutorial_1/7) However, I don't know how to view the module.

I know that if I can get a working example, I will be fine, but I can't. I am lost, and no matter how far I search all the guides miss the early steps, or make too much of an assumption.

#### test_form.info

```
name = Form example
description = My form example form API.
core = 6.x
package = Example form
```

#### test_form.module

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['some/form'] = array(
    'title' => 'Some Form',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('MYMODULE_some_form'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_some_form($form_state) {
  $form['item'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 'Default...',
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: What you're describing there isn't part of the form API, it's part of the menu API. Which part are you actually having trouble with? Installing the module? Visiting one of the paths you've defined? What happens when you visit `examples/form_example/tutorial` for example? Do you get an error? A 404? Have you defined the `form_example_tutorial_1` callback and placed it in your module file? Sorry for the barrage of questions but with the limited code in your question any answer would just be a wild guess

Comment: @Clive superstar drupal helper. This is truly where I am stuck. This is all new to me, well websites arn't but using the Form API and Drupal is.  Yes I get 404. I want to get the example in the link above working. My module file Is the form above, This is where I am lost following the guides for the form API. Where to put the Form API Code. Sorry for the basic understanding

Comment: I can not find anything that says ok start with this basic example, you need to put this here, that there, and there you have a basic form working. Once I have that I can understand what I need to do to develop the forms further. :-)

Comment: No apology necessary, we've all been there. You'll need a function in your module file with the following signature (for the first example) `function form_example_tutorial_1($form, &$form_state) {`. That will contain the code to define you form (remember to `return $form` at the end). Then it's just a matter of clearing Drupal's caches, because menu paths (or router items as they're sometimes known) are cached for performance reasons. After that it should work, in theory. If it doesn't, isolate the smallest bit of code you can that you think should work and post that here :)

Comment: Also, see the excellent [`hook_menu()` explanation](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62473/how-to-implement-hook-menu/62474#62474) to understand how the menu items you define are actually interacting with the page build process, and how `drupal_get_form()` is called to build the form based on the `page callback` you provide. Read it twice ;)

Comment: Ok still not showing but see my updated text if that says anything? thank you for your help

Comment: Hmm your code is perfect, so either...1. The module isn't installed, or 2. You haven't cleared the caches (Drupal's caches, not your browser cache)

Comment: I had to leave the office, I cleared the drupal cache. Is is possible linked to not having clean URLs? I'm home but I will get my test server up and give it another go tonight. Nothing like bringing work home!

Comment: Ah, yeah that would've been good to know ;) With clean URLs off **all** paths go like this: `http://mysite.com/index.php?q=some/path`

Comment: Ok i created a new drupal install. Created a fresh module folder, with .info and copied your example code into .module I enabled the module in drupal, cleared the cache. Without clean urls went to http://localhost/drupal7/?q=some/form as that is the name in the module file. Also tried index.php?q=some/form still not showing. Just get an error drupal couldnt find page. Is there something im missing

Comment: my info file is called formpractice.info and the module formpractice.module   Do they need to reference each other from within the .module?

Comment: No Drupal will pick the files up automatically, but the names of the hook functions you're implementing need to match the name of the module, so your `hook_menu()` would be called `formpractice_menu()`...maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than keep this going in the comments, here's a very basic form/menu example (un-tested but it should work).

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['some/form'] = array(
    'title' => 'Some Form',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('MYMODULE_some_form'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_some_form($form_state) {
  $form['item'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 'Default...',
  );

  return $form;
}
```

All of the above goes in a single module file. Once you install the new module (or clear the caches if it's already installed), you should see a basic form at `/some/form`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me through this. I will edit the question, and make it idiot proof for anyone else new to the module / form api system. All working Merci

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted. If you're going to add a solution it'd be great if you could do so as an answer (answering your own questions is encouraged). There might be a delay before you can do that though...

Answer (score 1):

I learnt by studying the Examples Module. Install the examples module (https://drupal.org/project/examples), enable form api example sub module in it. Follow the code.

API Documentation:
https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example%21form_example.module/group/form_example/7

A simple way to follow would be - look at the hook_menu function.

Look at the code here: http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/blob/HEAD:/form_example/form_example.module

The following code snippet builds the page at http://baseurl.com/examples/form_example - you can now follow along.

```
$items['examples/form_example'] = array(
   'title' => 'Form Example',
   'page callback' => 'form_example_intro',
   'access callback' => TRUE,
   'expanded' => TRUE,
);
```

Another useful piece of information is the form api examples at: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/6

For Drupal 7, look at: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi i tried the example module but when i enable it nothing loads in drupal so i had to disable it

Comment: you mean the site does not load? Try enabling only the form example module, you dont need to enable all the modules.

Comment: Yes I get a white screen. When I enable the form module. I downloaded the examples for developers drupal 6. But if I remove the module from the module folder drupal loads fine

Answer (score 1):

I was totally new to drupal, drupal modules (creating) and the form API.

Here is the basics to getting a simple form loaded with the menu link. Note the credits go to @Clive.

First of all I have a module in the module folder as follows.

**formpractice      - folder**

--**MYMODULE.info**

name = My Test Form

description = A very simple Test Form to get you up and running.

core = 7.x

--**MYMODULE.module** (It is important that the MYMODULE_menu = the module name. So in this case at the module is called MYMODULE thats what is here replacing the hook_menu. This was my main reason for my module not loading the simple form. I had called my module something different to what the hook_menu was utilising.Then from here the form is the 2nd function, that can be further developed using the API instructions. I hope this helps any new users to getting started with the FORM API.

```
<?php function MYMODULE_menu() {
$items['some/form'] = array(
'title' => 'Some Form',
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('MYMODULE_some_form'),
);

 return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_some_form($form_state) {
 $form['item'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Title'),
'#required' => TRUE,
'#default_value' => 'Default...',
 );

 return $form;
}
```