# How do I render a node queue as custom JSON?

Tags: nodes, 6, feeds

What would be the most sensible way to render a nodequeue queue in a custom JSON format (using Drupal 6)

We have a nodequeue that is both included in the UI in various places and served in a RSS feed.

I've found that I can use [`drupal_json()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json/6) to convert a PHP data structure to JSON so now I'm mostly after what would be the right place for this?

As a hack, I tried to use RSS feed and to have a custom template for the feed. My problem there is that a) it feels pretty hackish and b) in the "general template" available I don't have the content available.

(As background, I'm pretty new with Drupal so the answer here is probably pretty straight-forward)

Where to continue?

Comment: If it helps somebody, it also helped me to realize that nodequeue queues are actually kind of user-editable views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some Views JSON modules if you look around, but I typically do this outside of views itself.  And you are correct, you are halfway there.

You want to wire up a [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_menu/6) to create a custom path in a module.  See our [canonical question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62473/how-should-i-implement-hook-menu) on this topic for more information.

Then in the menu callback, you do use [`views_embed_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/6).  Something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_the_callback() {
  $output = views_embed_view('nodequeue_1', 'the_display');

  print drupal_json($output);
  exit;
}
```

You can also use the `$view` object directly:

```
function MYMODULE_the_callback() {
  $view = views_get_view('nodequeue_1');
  $view->set_display('the_display');
  $view->pre_execute();
  $view->execute();

  $output = $view->render();

  print drupal_json($output);
  exit;
}
```

Using the later form, you can poke through the `$view` object and tailor your JSON accordingly.

This should give you a head start.

Keep in mind as you research this, that the plumbing is a little different for rendering JSON in Drupal 6 vs 7.  In 7, you would use `drupal_json_output()` and `drupal_exit()`;