# Is there any online tutorial explains how can I map the requested URL to actions' code in drupal 7?

Tags: 7

I'm beginner to Drupal 7. As I know, when the user request for example the URL: (**www.example.com/node/123**) then the Node module will responsible on responding to this request. How can I create a simple php function in my custom module so that it can respond to a specific request generated from my custom page or my custom form submission? for example: **www.example.com/mymodule/blablabla**?

Comment: did you try pathauto mmodule ?

Comment: Actually no. but I believe that redirecting the http request to php function to handle the request is the functionality of the core/bootstrap of Drupal, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), you will need to implement this hook on your custom module to register path in drupal.

> Define menu items and page callbacks.
>
> This hook enables modules to register paths in order to define how URL
>   requests are handled. Paths may be registered for URL handling only,
>   or they can register a link to be placed in a menu (usually the
>   Navigation menu). A path and its associated information is commonly
>   called a "menu router item". This hook is rarely called (for example,
>   when modules are enabled), and its results are cached in the database.

Since you are beginner, First I would suggest you to learn about [hook system for drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/292).

Checkout [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62473/how-should-i-implement-hook-menu) for detailed use of hook_menu.

Comment: You mean that any requested URL or form data submission to Drupal will be handled by invoking all functions in all modules that implements hook_menu()? even if it is form data submission?

Comment: short answer will be yes.. you will need to explore more on `hook_menu` and the options available.

Comment: No, making a single page request will not invoke the callback function of every single router path. That would be insane