# Is there a way to call "access callback" with parameters?

Tags: routes

I have:

```
function hook_menu()  {
    $items = array();
    $items['experiment-2'] = array(
        'title' => 'Experiment 2',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('experiment_form'),
        'access callback' => 'user_can_access_experiment',
        'file' => 'includes/experiment-2.form.inc',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
      );

    ...
```

This will call:

```
function user_can_access_experiment() { }
```

But I want to be able to call it something like:

```
function user_can_access_experiment($experimentID) { }
```

And then somehow let `hook_menu` call the function as `user_can_access_experiment(1)` or `user_can_access_experiment(2)` or whatever.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is covered in [How should I implement hook\_menu()?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62473/how-should-i-implement-hook-menu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your query right the `access callback` needs to accept a parameter based on which it decides whether or not to return TRUE for the menu path. This should be achievable using `access arguments`, like

`'access arguments' => array($experimentID),`

quoting from the [hook_menu API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)

> "access arguments": An array of arguments to pass to the access
>   callback function, with path component substitution as described
>   above. If the access callback is inherited (see above), the access
>   arguments will be inherited with it, unless overridden in the child
>   menu item.

The passed argument, in your case the `$experimentID` could be either from any custom computation like a value from the user object or even a part of your query parameters.

Comment: Given '/foo/bar/barfoo' as path and `'access callback' => '_mymodule_check_arg'`, `'access arguments' => array(2)` would pass 'barfoo' into `_mymodule_check_arg($arg_from_path)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "access arguments" to indicate it.
This array key is waiting for an array.

cf : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

Answer (score 1):

> "**access callback**": A function returning TRUE if the user has
>   access rights to this menu item, and FALSE if not. It can also be a
>   boolean constant instead of a function, and you can also use numeric
>   values (will be cast to boolean). Defaults to user_access() unless a
>   value is inherited from the parent menu item; only
>   MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK items can inherit access callbacks. To use the
>   user_access() default callback, you must specify the permission to
>   check as 'access arguments' (see below).
>
> "**access arguments**": An array of arguments to pass to the access
>   callback function, with path component substitution as described
>   above. If the access callback is inherited (see above), the access
>   arguments will be inherited with it, unless overridden in the child
>   menu item.

This example may helps you:

```
function hook_menu()  {
    $items = array();
    $items['experiment-2'] = array(
        'title' => 'Experiment 2',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('experiment_form'),
        'access callback' => 'user_has_role',
        'access arguments' => array(array('Role 1', 'Role 2')),
        'file' => 'includes/experiment-2.form.inc',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
      );

    return $items;
}


function user_has_role($roles) {
    if (user_is_logged_in()) {
        global $user;
        if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if (in_array($role, $user->roles)) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```